# To whom do we add the suffix (SAW)?

Tags: prophets, greetings, salawat

Prompted from [this discussion,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5904/discussion-between-tamer-shlash-and-nesreena) there are various opinions as to who we are allowed to add the suffix sallah Allahu allehe wa salam.

> Allah and His angels send blessings on the Prophet: O ye that believe! Send ye blessings on him, and salute him with all respect. 33:56

From this ayah we can infer that we must use it for prophet Muhammad (SAAWS) but what about the other prophets?

We say in our prayers that Allah send his blessings to prophet Muhammad and Abraham, and his Aal (family), if that's the case, then we can use the suffix to more people other than Prophet Muhammad.

So who do we use this suffix for, Prophet Muhammad, Prophet Abraham, or all the prophets?

Answer (score 1):

Phrases

> "May Allah pray on him and grant him peace.": (Arabic: صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم‎ ṣall Allāhu ʿalay-hi wa-sallam - S.A.W., SAAW, or SAAS)

and

> "May Allah grant peace and pray on him and his family.": (Arabic: صلى
>   الله عليه وآله‎ ṣall Allahu ʿalayhi wa-’ālih - S.A.W.W.)

are used specifically after saying the name of the last prophet of Islam, Muhammad (ﷺ).

Phrase

> "Peace be upon him": (Arabic: عليه السلام‎ ʿalayhi s-salām - A.S.)

follows after naming any prophet other than Muhammad (ﷺ), or one of the archangels (i.e. Jibreel, Mikaeel, etc.)

About other people:

> The great scholar of Hadith and Shafi’i jurist (faqih), Imam al-Nawawi
>   (may Allah be pleased with him) states: “It is recommended (mustahab)
>   to seek Allah’s pleasure (taraddi) and mercy (tarahhum) for the
>   Companions (sahaba), their followers (tabi’un) and those after them
>   such as the scholars, worshippers and all good people. Hence, one
>   should say: “may Allah be pleased with him” or “may Allah have mercy
>   on him” (Arabic: رضي الله عنه Radi-Allahu anhu), and other similar phrases.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read our FAQ.  Questions here are required to have citations and have links to cited content in an answer.  Can you give a link for that quote by Annawawi? and can you also provide some citations for the rest of the answer? thank you.

Comment: @al Salam. According to the page [daruliftaa.com](http://www.daruliftaa.com/question?txt_questionid=q-10345239) quote by Annawawi is in his book Kitab al-Adhkar, at page 100.
Other information I found on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him_(Islam))